# Invalidate JSON file from TAGpro analytics, can't process on R

Tags: r, json

```
{"1":{"server":"tagpro-chord.koalabeast.com","port":8008,"official":true,"group":"","date":1432576197,"timeLimit":12,"duration":22562,"finished":true,"players":[{"auth":true,"name":"RoDyMaRy","flair":105,"degree":99,"score":31,"points":25,"team":1,"events":"AREVYIpPCAe0QCBSIAisARCvARK\/ARCjARArIAgDARAfARCjARArARArCAbrQCDMCAdDAKHyQKELAFRmCAQPQKD3ARV6ARCjIAgrAREkARCjARBnAREbIAg9ARAhARArIAQBECYAUIoBETQBECsAUAsBEA8BECsBEdAgCTAAUS4AURtAF\/EAU9YIBD1AoMlAGDIgDC0ICAHqAKCQQKELIAmIAFC7AFFU"}}
```

Hello,

I got 962 mb JSON file with up line example. just shared one line with you, when i stream in or fromJSON got EOL problem, but i can't fix data with my own because it's almost big data, can you help how can get dataframe and csv file on it?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_json_files.htm

Comment: Read in the data frame with rjson. If you still need CSV write the data frame with `write.csv()` into a separate file.

Comment: I did all versions you said things. But i have problem "EOL" when i use fromJSON or streamin func, see in explorer "8 of LİST" ..

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the post. It seems the JSON data is not well formatted. e.g. missing braces or quotation marks. Try to load the JSON file with your Brower or IDE Editor with syntax highlighting. Most of them give you more detailed error messages. If you are on linux you could use the jq  command line tool. I don't know if this is also available for windows or Mac.